# Mono for Android

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an Android app using C# and VS2010. I have installed the JDK 1.6, Android SDK, VS2010, and the add-on for Android, Mono for Android. I set the path for the JDK and Android as my system variables. Everything installs okay, but when I try to run VS2010,
I get an error message:

> Android SDK not found. Please check whether all the components are
>   installed and that Mono for Android configuration points to an
>   existing Android SDK path

Answer (score 2):

You must set **Android SDK Location** and should **Android NDK Location**.

In visual studio go to `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin`

Answer (score 1):

Your path should contain both `<sdk-folder>\tools` and `<sda-folder>\platform-tools` to function properly.